# Is it possible to crop an image captured from the Camera on Android without returning to the app?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera

The goal is to allow the user to capture a new image with the camera on an Android device. I need the final image to be a square. I don't see a way to constrain the size of the capture image without using the Camera class and doing a lot more work.

What I would like to be able to do is start the camera activity using the `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent action and have the Crop action be performed right after the image is capture. I am able to get the desired behavior by using the `"com.android.camera.action.CROP"` action in `onActivityResult` when returning from the camera but this returns the user to my app before starting the Crop action.

To summarize, what I have now is:

`My-app -> Camera -> My-app -> Crop`

and ideally what I would like is:

`My-app -> Camera -> Crop -> My-app`

(If it is possible to tell the image capture intent to use a specific size when opening the camera that would be great if I just missed how to do that.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am able to get the desired behavior by using the "com.android.camera.action.CROP" action in onActivityResult when returning from the camera but this returns the user to my app before starting the Crop action.

[Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). Few devices will have an activity that supports your undocumented `Intent` action.

> and ideally what I would like is: My-app -> Camera -> Crop -> My-app

You are welcome to use the camera APIs and [an image-cropping library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) to do all of this work yourself.

Or, you are welcome to continue using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, but do the image-cropping yourself.

Or, you are welcome to stick with your existing code, bearing in mind that your image will not be cropped on most Android devices.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Is many android devices will not have CROP intent ? .....Is library are the only way to implement that @CommonsWare

Comment: @KoVartthan: That `Intent` action is undocumented. There is no requirement for any device to have an activity that responds to it. You should assume that hundreds of millions of Android devices do not have such an activity. "Is library are the only way to implement that" -- you could not offer cropping. Or, you could offer cropping on devices that have such an activity, but then many of your users will wonder why your app does not work well on their device. Using a library is not difficult.